# Problem with django-avatar

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to implement django-avatar in my Django app on a production server.
The problem is that the form for upload images accepts every type of files! This means a user can upload also a `file.php`. So, I thought django-avatar handle this. How can I fix? I want the form accepts only images.

Comment: Fred, FYI, installing 1.0.4 from PYPI still does not solve the problem. If you go and check your site media folder under avatar, you will notice that the files that non image files are still sittting on the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most current version of django-avatar contains the fix to only allow image uploads. What version are you using? The pypi version (currently 1.0) is old and does not contain the updates.

Download the newest version from https://github.com/ericflo/django-avatar

Comment: I've `django_avatar-1.0.5-py2.6.egg` installed with `easy_install`. It's the more recent.

Comment: Now I've put in `settings.py` this: `AVATAR_ALLOWED_FILE_EXTS = ('.jpg', '.png')`, but I can upload every file type again.

Comment: Fixed installing the last zipball version. Ty.